# Error setting variable to the length of an array in bash

Tags: bash

I have the snippet below in a larger script to basically take my balances out of ledger into two arrays so I can print them the way I want to view them.

```
#!/bin/bash
assets=("assets:checking" "assets:google wallet" "assets:savings" "assets:cash")
assets-bal=()

num=${#assets[@]}
for $i in {0..${num}}
do
  read -a tmp <<< `ledger -f finances balance "${assets[${i}]}"`
  assets-bal[${i}]=tmp[0]
  echo "${assets[${i}]}   ${assets-bal[${i}]}"
done
```

Every time I try runnning the script I get the error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `num=${#assets[@]}'
`num=${#assets[@]}'
```

From my searching, there should be nothing wrong with that line and I just keep coming up empty trying to find a reason why it won't work.

Can anybody point out where I'm wrong?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably

```
assets-bal=()
```

Variable names must not contain a dash. You are limited to underscores.

I don't know how `bash` interprets `assets-bal=()` but it considers that an incomplete command which has to be finished on another line. Just run that line in a shell to see what I mean.

Comment: This line is interpreted as the start of a function declaration. After `assets-bal=()`, try `{ echo wibble; }` then `assets-bal=`. Bash allows function names with nonstandard characters like `-` and `=`, but it doesn't allow function bodies to be a simple command.

Answer (score 2):

Brace expansion does not support variables since it is done [before variables are expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion). Use `seq` instead, if you absolutely must:

```
for i in $(seq 0 ${num})
```

Or (much more preferable) get the array keys directly:

```
for i in "${!assets[@]}"
```

(Also, `for i in ..`, not `for $i in ..`.)

---

[Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172391/70524) got the first error. Once you fix that, this will probably be the next error.

---

And instead of

```
read -a tmp <<< `ledger -f finances balance "${assets[${i}]}"`
```

Consider using:

```
tmp=($(ledger -f finances balance "${assets[${i}]}"))
```

The `()` outside the command substitution converts it into an array.

Comment: @Hauke Very sorry for the typo!

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely use both of those. I probably would have caught the $i error, I just hadn't made it that far with the script failing earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax ERROR : you can't use a `-` in the name of a variable.

```
assets-bal
```

should be replaced by

```
 assets_bal
```

For the loop, you can use a `for` loop in the C style :

```
for ((i=0; i<${num}; i++)); do
```

Comment: You have a typo in variable name

Answer (score -1):

I think maybe you're relying a little too heavily on array types there - and variables in general. If I understand what you're doing up there correctly, I suspect this should do much of the same:

```
for a in checking google\ wallet savings cash
do  a=assets:$a
    printf "$a\t%d\n" "$(ledger -f finances balance "$a")"
done
```

That could probably be improved upon a great deal by somehow getting a reading of all values for `$a` above at once in a stream and then arranging it with a scripted editor like `sed` or similar. In general a shell variable is a pretty awful place to keep information of any value - or of any significant size for that matter. A shell variable should store only enough information to make retrieving actual information from a file more manageable.

Written as a shell function, the above might look like:

```
assets() if   [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
         then while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
              do    printf "assets:%s\t%d\n" "$1" "$(
                    ledger -f finances balance "assets:$1")"
              shift;done
         else assets checking google\ wallet savings cash
         fi
```

...and could be called like:

```
assets
```

...for your default list, or like...

```
assets cash checking
```

...for a different list without every setting a single shell variable value at all.